# duda sobre consutla mysql

Tags: mysql

tengo la siguiente duda

Tengo 2 tablas vehículos y accesos.

En la tabla vehículos quiero obtener la ultima fecha registrada de la tabla accesos

Tabla vehículos

```
 id_vehiculo - vehículo   - nombre

  3349793 -   Nissan       -   Pedro
```

TABLA ACCESOS

```
  id_vehiculo -   fecha 

    3349793 -   2018-01-08 17:34    
    3349793 -   2018-01-08 17:37    
    3356512 -   2018-01-11 18:02    
    3356512 -   2018-01-12 09:09   
    3349793 -   2018-01-04 16:16   
    3356512 -   2018-01-04 16:32    
    3356512 -   2018-01-04 18:15
```

Necesito este resultado sin cargar tanto la consulta , teniendo en cuenta que un vehículo puede tener accesos ilimitados

Resultado

```
 id_vehiculo - vehículo   - nombre - fecha 

     3349793 -   Nissan   -   Pedro  - 2018-01-08 17:37
```

Estaba utilizando esta consulta pero no logro el resultado deseado

```
SELECT
   vehículos.id_vehiculo,
   vehículos.vehículo,
   vehículos.nombre,
   accesos.fecha
FROM vehículos, accesos
WHERE (vehículos.id_vehiculo= accesos.id_vehiculo)

GROUP BY  id_vehiculo
ORDER BY accesos.fecha desc
```

Comment: Por favor, comparte el código que hasta ahora has escrito

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a Stack Overflow. Las preguntas sin código no son bien recibidas por la comunidad. Pásate por [esta sección](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que aprendas como realizar una pregunta y evitar que te la cierren.

Answer (score 1):

Podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```
SELECT V.id_vehiculo, V.vehiculo, V.nombre,
        ( SELECT MAX( A.fecha ) FROM accesos A WHERE A.id_vehiculo = V.id_vehiculo )
    FROM vehiculos V
```

Te recomiendo que en tu tabla de accesos no uses id_vehiculo por confusiones y ambigüedad, te recomiendo lo generes como vehiculo_id

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar la cláusula `INNER JOIN` para relacionar las dos tablas y debes agregar `LIMIT 1` a la última línea para que solo te muestre información del acceso mas reciente.

`ORDER BY accesos.fecha desc LIMIT 1`

La consulta debería quedar así:

```
SELECT 
  vehiculos.id_vehiculo, 
  vehiculos.vehiculo, 
  vehiculos.nombre, 
  accesos.fecha
FROM vehiculos INNER JOIN accesos
ON vehiculos.id_vehiculo = accesos.id_vehiculo
ORDER BY accesos.fecha DESC LIMIT 1
GROUP BY vehiculos.id_vehiculo
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con:

```
SELECT
    vehículos.id_vehiculo,
    vehículos.vehículo,
    vehículos.nombre,
    MAX(accesos.fecha) AS accesos_fecha
FROM vehículos, accesos
WHERE (vehículos.id_vehiculo= accesos.id_vehiculo)

GROUP BY  id_vehiculo
ORDER BY accesos_fecha desc
```

Nota adicional, te sugiero que evites el CROSS JOIN con el tiempo y la cantidad de datos cargará bastante la consulta. Usa INNER JOIN:

```
SELECT
    vehículos.id_vehiculo,
    vehículos.vehículo,
    vehículos.nombre,
    MAX(accesos.fecha) AS accesos_fecha
FROM vehículos
INNER JOIN accesos
    ON vehículos.id_vehiculo = accesos.id_vehiculo
GROUP BY  id_vehiculo
ORDER BY accesos_fecha desc
```